# Jquery dynamically created element won't ClearTimeout();

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a hover popup window with event information for a school project.

when i'm not hovering the popup i need to to be removed, but if you enter within a second apart it should clear my timeout. but it wont.

here's my code :

```
var timer;
var events = [1, 10, 18, "Museum De Vishal", 'event informatie', 'imgpath'];

$('.event:not(.order)').hover(function () {
    var offset = $("#planyourday").offset();
    var offsetTop = $(this).offset();
    var width = $("#planyourday").width();
    var height = $("#planyourday").height();
    var eventHeader = events[3];
    var eventImg = events[5];
    var eventInfo = events[4];

    $('#planyourday').append("<div title='press here for more information' class='hidden meh' id='eventInfo'><div class='arrow_box'></div><div class='eventMenu'><h2 class='eventHeader'></h2><div title='Close this' class='eventRemove'>X</div></div> <br /><img class='eventImg' /><br /><p class='eventInfo'></p></div>");
    $('#eventInfo').css({ "top": offsetTop.top + 35 + "px", "left": offsetTop.left + "px", "height": (height - 8) + "px", "bottom": -height + "px" });
    $('.arrow_box').css({ left: offsetTop.left + "px" });
    $('.eventHeader').html(eventHeader);
    $('.eventImg').attr('src', eventImg);
    $('.eventInfo').html(eventInfo);
    $('#eventInfo').slideDown();
}).children('.order').mouseover(function () {
    return false;
});


$('body').on("mouseenter", "#eventInfo, .event", function () {
    $(this).css({ border: "1px solid red" })
    ClearTimer();
});


$('body').on("mouseout", "#eventInfo, .event", function () {
    StartTimer();
});
function ClearTimer() {
    clearTimeout(timer);
}

function StartTimer() {
    timer = window.setTimeout(function () {
        $('#eventInfo').remove();
    }, 5000);
}
```

i hope you guys can help me, Thnx :)

update: here's a JSFiffle, http://jsfiddle.net/3uzo25cj/

update: i used the wrong mouse event i used mouseout and should have used mouseleave.

Comment: It would be easier for others to understand if you create a jsfiddle.

Comment: thank you for your input i shall add one :)

Answer (score 0):

You should clear the running timer before starting a new one:

```
function ClearTimer() {
    clearTimeout(timer);
}

function StartTimer() {
    ClearTimer();

    timer = window.setTimeout(function () {
        $('#eventInfo').remove();
    }, 5000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('body').on("mouseleave", "#eventInfo, .event", function () {
    StartTimer();
});
```

Comment: Good catch! You are right `mouseleave` should match `mouseenter`. Still, I would also add my fix.